# Omniauth Testing Error, Devise/Rails/Rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, devise, omniauth

Appreciate any opinions out there.
This is the exact error I am getting. I can't figure out why.

```
No route matches {:action=>"users/auth/:facebook", :controller=>"omniauth_callbacks"} missing required keys: [:action]
```

- Omniauth Controller

  ```
  def facebook
    auth = env["omniauth.auth"]
    @user = User.connect_to_facebook(request.env["omniauth.auth"],current_user)

    if @user.persisted?
      flash[:notice] = I18n.t "devise.omniauth_callbacks.success"
      sign_in_and_redirect @user, :event => :authentication
    else
      session["devise.facebook_uid"] = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
      redirect_to new_user_registration_url
    end
  end
  ```
- User Model

  ```
   devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
   :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable,:omniauthable        
    has_many :games
    has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy

  def self.connect_to_facebook(auth, signed_in_resource=nil)
   user = User.where(:provider => auth.provider, :uid => auth.uid).first
   if user
    return user
   else
    registered_user = User.where(:email => auth.info.email).first
    if registered_user
     return registered_user
    else
     user = User.create(username:auth.info.name,
                        provider:auth.provider,
                        uid:auth.uid,
                        email:auth.info.email,
                        password:Devise.friendly_token[0,20],)

    end
   end
  end
  ```
- config/initializers/devise.rb

  ```
  require 'omniauth-facebook'
  config.omniauth :facebook, ENV['FACEBOOK_PUBLIC'], ENV['FACEBOOK_SECRET'], scope: 'email', info_fields: 'email, name'
  ```
- routes

  ```
  devise_for :users, :controllers => { :omniauth_callbacks => "omniauth_callbacks" }
  root to: 'home#index'
  ```

-spec/controllers/omniauth_callbacks_controller_spec.rb

```
    require 'rails_helper'

    RSpec.describe OmniauthCallbacksController, type: :controller do

    def set_omniauth(opts = {})
      default = {:provider => :facebook,
                 :uuid     => "1234",
                 :facebook => {
                                :email => "foobar@example.com",
                                :gender => "Male",
                                :first_name => "foo",
                                :last_name => "bar"
                      }
                }

      credentials = default.merge(opts)
      provider = credentials[:provider]
      user_hash = credentials[provider]

      OmniAuth.config.test_mode = true

      OmniAuth.config.mock_auth[provider] = {
        'uid' => credentials[:uuid],
        "extra" => {
        "user_hash" => {
          "email" => user_hash[:email],
          "first_name" => user_hash[:first_name],
          "last_name" => user_hash[:last_name],
          "gender" => user_hash[:gender]
          }
        }
      }
    end

    def set_invalid_omniauth(opts = {})

      credentials = { :provider => :facebook,
                      :invalid  => :invalid_crendentials
                     }.merge(opts)

      OmniAuth.config.test_mode = true
      OmniAuth.config.mock_auth[credentials[:provider]] = credentials[:invalid]

    end 

    describe "GET '/users/auth/facebook'" do

      before(:each) do
        set_omniauth
        request.env["devise.mapping"] = Devise.mappings[:user]
        request.env["omniauth.auth"] = OmniAuth.config.mock_auth[:facebook]

        get "users/auth/facebook"
        request.env["omniauth.auth"] = OmniAuth.config.mock_auth[:facebook]
      end

      it "should set user_id" do
        expect(session[:user_id]).to eq(User.last.id)
      end
    end
    end
```

Thanks in advance to anyone who can shed some light or at least give me some ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're writing a controller test, you should provide a controller action in `get` call, not an actual url, like this:

```
get :facebook
```

Or, you can change your test to a [`request` spec](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails#request-specs), this way you'll be testing the whole stack, and it would work with the url.

Comment: Ok, Thank you. I seem to have hit another error, but at least now I am accessing the Oauth.